# Drilldown to multiple series from different groups - Highcharter (in R)

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm looking for a way to drill down from different groups into multiple series using Highcharter for R.  Essentially, I'd like to reproduce this example some in High Charts (from jsfiddle) - 
http://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/v1o8dga9/3/

Here's some code that gets me close to this -

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4), y = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5), key = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 3)),
             drilldown = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3), rep("c", 3)))

drill1 <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3),
  y = c(3, 3, 1)
)
drill1 <- list_parse2(drill1)

drill2 <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,4),
  y = c(1, 5, 1)
)
drill2 <- list_parse2(drill2)

drill3 <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,4),
  y = c(4, 3, 1)
)
drill3 <- list_parse2(drill3)


hchart(df, "line", 
       hcaes(x = x, y = y, group = key),
       color = c("#A63A50", "#37123C", "#DDA77B"),
       drilldown = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(line = list(marker = list(enabled = FALSE), legendIndex = 1)) %>% 
  hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = list(
      list(
        id = "a",
        data = drill1
      ),
      list(
        id = "b",
        data = drill2
      ),
      list(
        id = "c",
        data = drill3
      )
    )
  )
```

This script lets me drill down to three different charts, one for each group. However, each drill down chart has only one series.  I cannot figure out how to have **multiple series** in the drill down charts.

It's important that the drill down charts include buttons to return to the main chart (as in my example and the jsfiddle example).  Also, I need the ability to drill into different charts from different groups, not just one group.

So basically I need the jsfiddle example reproduced in highcharter.  I suspect the solution involves some javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite all from provided jsFiddle into R using **JS("...")** function.

Here is an example of it:

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4), y = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5), key = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 3)),
             drilldown = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3), rep("c", 3)))

drill1 <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3),
  y = c(3, 3, 1)
)
drill1 <- list_parse2(drill1)

drill2 <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,4),
  y = c(1, 5, 1)
)
drill2 <- list_parse2(drill2)

drill3 <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,4),
  y = c(4, 3, 1)
)
drill3 <- list_parse2(drill3)


hchart(df, "line", 
       hcaes(x = x, y = y, group = key),
       color = c("#A63A50", "#37123C", "#DDA77B"),
       drilldown = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_chart(events = list(drilldown = JS("function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            var chart = this,
              series = [{
                data: [5, 5, 5, 3, 2]
              }, {
                data: [3, 3, 7, 3, 3]
              }];

            chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series[0]);
            chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series[1]);
            chart.applyDrilldown();
        }"))) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(line = list(marker = list(enabled = FALSE), legendIndex = 1)) %>% 
  hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = list(
      list(
        id = "a",
        data = drill1
      ),
      list(
        id = "b",
        data = drill2
      ),
      list(
        id = "c",
        data = drill3
      )
    )
  )
```

And simplified jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nx6czgwf

Now you just need to prepare your data and use code from your jsFiddle.

Comment: This works beautifully.  Thanks for your help.  The trick is to copy the javascript for everything after 'function(e)' and paste this into events = list(drilldown  = JS([paste here])), just as you did in this example.